# 2sxc Error: can't delete items, found entities assigned children

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a newly deployed site running Dnn v9.10.02 and 2sxc v13.0.0. I am building a custom app that contains an Event entity and an Organization entity. One of the fields of Event is an entity type of Organization to mark which organization is hosting the event. When I try to delete an Event using the TagToolBar on the frontend I receive an error that it can't delete the entity. If I try to delete the same Event entity through the backend 2sxc panel the error message lets me know that the reason for the error is due to having an Organization entity as a child. If I remove the Organization child entity I can delete the Event using either the front end TagToolbar or the backend panel. Leaving the Organization in place while trying to delete the Event through the backend 2sxc panel I get the option to force delete the Event, which works as expected. Is there a way to ignore this error, or to at least get the force delete option, while using the frontend TagToolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ATM this is not possible - for now on purpose, because simple users tend to hurt themselves by accident since they ignore these warnings and later blame the developer for the problem ;)

So ATM there is no direct plan to change this.